# Print a nested list line by line in reverse order using list comprehension and for loop - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, printing, nested-lists

```
my_list =[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

I am trying my best to print `my_list` of the form:

```
3 2 1
6 5 4
10 9 8 7
```

This is my output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

It seems really simple in "python ways",
 Thanks!

Comment: `print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, i[::-1])) for i in my_list))`

Comment: why did you create a question and answer it immediately?

Comment: [Nothing wrong with answering your own questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MEHTOD 1**

We can use list comprehension, Slices and `.join()` operator.

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]

for item in my_list:
    print ' '.join(str(x) for x in item[::-1])
```

output:

> ```
> 3 2 1
> 6 5 4
> 10 9 8 7
> ```

**MEHTOD 2**

We can use nested for loop and Slices operator.

```
for xs in my_list:
    for x in xs[::-1]:
        print x,
    print
```

And `print()` by default prints new-line characters at the end unless you use: `print(end="")` or if you were using Python 2.x `print t,` would work.

output:

> ```
> 3 2 1
> 6 5 4
> 10 9 8 7
> ```

Comment: Why is the question tagged Python 3.x when none of these methods will run in Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer I could come up with is:

```
for nested_list in my_list:
  print([val for val in nested_list[::-1]])
```

As expressed in other answers passing `::-1` to the nested list reverses the order in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The [::-1] slice reverses the list in the for loop (but won't actually modify your list "permanently"):

```
def reverse_list(my_list):
    new_list = []
    for sub_list in my_list:
        new_list.append(sub_list[::-1])
    return new_list


test_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]];
reversed_lists = reverse_list(test_list)
for reversed_list in reversed_lists:
    print reversed_list
```